# SOQL Query Find User License Expiration Date

Tags: apex, soql

I want to know when all User Licenses will be expire "Expiration Date I want to know "
How can i Find it by apex soql query .

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Expiration date of all licenses under "Company Info" which is accessible via the organization object. Unfortunately, in the object User License there is no expiration date, only in PermissionSetLicense. However, the User License seems to be linked to Profile, as you can query via parent-child relationship Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM User.