# User license expiration date

Tags: soql, api

I want to know how I can fetch "user License Expiration date" using API. Could someone please help me with that.
I have gone through similar questions and came to know that we can see that information in UI, but I want to fetch that with API. Information about the Object where the user license expiration information is stored can also suffice my query, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm?search_text=expiration) for UserLicense does not have an expiration date field to be retrieved using API so unfortunately, it is not possible to retrieve using API.

This information is not exposed under API or Apex. But it is available on the user license related list on the company information page. If something is not exposed in api, but available on set up page then there is no way to retrieve it using API. I have seen some customers do page scrapping to get that information in code which is not recommended though

This looks like it would fall under a feature request. I would request you to post this as an idea on [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideasearch)

I also suggest taking a look at this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274513/soql-query-find-user-license-expiration-date) where a similar discussion has been made